# What does return with a ternary operator mean?

Tags: c, return, compare, conditional-operator

I currently have a problem to read this code.
Does anyone know what it does ?

```
if (c == a)
    return q[a] ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Do you know what the ternary operator means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement

```
return q[a] ? 1 : 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
// Exact type of "zero" depends on the type of q[a]
if (q[a] != 0) 
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

Or

```
return !!q[a];
```

Comment: Ty for taking the time ! yep thats it

Answer (score 1):

The code inside if gets evaluated in order matching operator precedence.

So first `a + 1` is evaluated and then `b == (a + 1)`.

If `b` is equal to `(a + 1)` then if `q[a]` is `true` `1`, is returned, otherwise `0`.

See [C# operators and expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) or [Precedence and order of evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=vs-2019)
(depending on the language, you want to google "language name" + operator precedence).

Answer (score 0):

If q[a] is non-zero it returns 1 otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

If `c==a` and `q[a]` = true return `1` otherwise return `0`.